# Добавление виртуального процессора Debian

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Имеется VirtualBox, на нём стоит Debian 8, в настройках машины выставлено количество процессоров на 2, но в debian по прежнему показывается как один.

Как добавить в системе процессор?

**VBoxManage.exe" showvminfo deb_mfadmin**

http://pastebin.com/pHe4bzUa

**cat /proc/cpuinfo**

http://pastebin.com/LLnh3hUE

Comment: может быть, вы неверно интерпретируете наблюдаемое? приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу, вывод команд (это текст, текстом и прикладывайте, не картинкой, а текстом): 1. в host-системе: `$ vboxmanage showvminfo имя-вм`; 2. внутри вм: `$ cat /proc/cpuinfo` // изменить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спасибо за ответ. добавил

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/365615/416190

Comment: только 64 разрядность?